# Godaddy Domain Email Accounts with Azure Hosting

Tags: azure, email, azure-active-directory

I have purchased a domain from godaddy and a web hosting from azure cloud. Now I want to create email accounts for that domain. Can anyone guide me how to create.

Well if I had purchased a domain with hosting from godaddy then its a piece of cake to create email accounts because godaddy give us with its hosting.

But I am stuck with this scenario that domain is from godaddy and a web hosting from azure.

Comment: Are you planning yo use services like Gsuite or Zoho mail?

Comment: Well as I said if I had purchased a domain with hosting from godaddy then its not a problem. I want free solution :) because I already purchased domain and hosting.

Comment: Okay, then you can use **Zoho mail's Forever free plan**. You can find it at the bottom of this [page](https://www.zoho.com/mail/zohomail-pricing.html). You can make up to 5 emails with 5GB/mail and 25MB attachments.

Comment: Azure does not have an email service.  Microsoft offers Office 365 but it's not free.

Comment: @AjaySivan Thanks, your comment is the answer of my question (Y)

Comment: Then I have added it as an answer. Please accept it, so that others can also make use of it.

Comment: You do realise that email runs on an email server while your website runs on a web server. So, you bought web server space from Microsoft and domain from goddady, it really has nothing to do with email. I see that you have already found a solution but email usually costs money. I think go daddy themselves have a cheaper solution. I personally use Office 365 which is really good

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use services like G Suite, Zoho mail, etc.

If you want a lifelong free solution with some limitations you can use Zoho mail's Forever free plan. You can create up to 5 emails and you will get 5GB/email and a maximum attachment size of 25MB. You can find the pack at the bottom of [this page](https://www.zoho.com/mail/zohomail-pricing.html).

Comment: Thanks for the help, although its solve my problem but I am amazed that if someone purchased a hosting from azure then he/she needs to purchase email address separately...

Comment: @QuadBeans-Dev Yes, you have to. And I think nowadays most people rely on some services like Google Gsuite, Zoho, Office 365, etc. Not only because people are looking for a better custom email solution but also these services provide much more than just email service. You can get collaboration & productivity tool like calendar, mobile apps and more.

Comment: Thanks, I am using Zoho now.